# Return a new array with the first and last element of the passed array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am not sure what I am missing. Need the new array to return the first and last element of the passed array.

```
var firstAndLast = function(array){

  var newArray = new Array();
  newArray [0] = array[0]
  newArray [1] = array[3]
  return plate;
}

For Example:
var array = ['one', 3, 'cool', 4];
firstAndLast(array); // returns ['one', 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the first and last element, and return that in an array. I'm not sure where `plate` comes from, but in general your function is 'correct' in the sense that you create a new array and set the first and second elements to the first and last elements of the passed array. You just need to return `newArray`.

But what if the the 4th element *isn't* the last one in the array? Then you'd have to make it more general:

```js
var array = ['one', 3, 'cool', 4];

var firstAndLast = function(arr) {
  return [arr[0], arr[arr.length - 1]]; //No need for new Array(), and you can just assign items in positions inline
}

console.log(firstAndLast(array));
```

The above code reduces the function into 3 lines, as it returns an array literal, with the first element as `arr[0]`, the first element of the passed array. The second element is `arr[arr.length - 1]`, which is the last element. Consider this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The length currently is 5, and the last element is accessed by `arr[4]`. Now, just subtract one from the length to get 4, and access the last element. `arr[arr.length - 1]` in this case would yield `5`.